# I've got the FBI Cybercrime virus on my laptop, does anyone know of a method of removing it?

Tags: malware

How do I remove FBI Cybercrime?

Comment: Also I just added Ubuntu 14.01 would clearing the hard drive and reinstalling ubunut work?

Comment: Yes it likely would - how did you get this virus and what are the symptoms - what doesn't work etc (is it under Wine or something?). Can you access a TTY with 'Ctrl'+'Alt'+'F2'?

Comment: check your proxy settings, if in Firefox - Edit -> Prefrences -> Avanced -> Network -> Connection -> Settings. Then report back.

Comment: Also check in Ubuntu’s system settings -> System Settings -> Network -> Network proxy

Comment: Close voters: It may still be possible to get part of the "virus" that attacks the browser settings in Ubuntu. afaik it just changes the browsers proxy settings to redirect pages.

Comment: @AlexCyote can you add more information to your post, the browsers you use, the browsers that are affected. Your Ubuntu Version, did you mean 14.10? also what happens, can you close the browser?